# html FORM tag messing up my css display inline

Tags: html, css

when I add the `<form>` tag in my HTML, it messes up the "inline" display of my form.

HTML that works:

```
<div class="header">
<a href="index.html"> <img src="icon.png" width="45"></a>
<div class="headertitle">TITLE</div>

    <select class="form-field">
    <option>test</option> 
    </select>

    <select class="form-field" >
    <option>test2</option>
    </select>

    <div class="headermenu">test3</div> 

    <select class="form-field" >
    <option>test4</option>
    </select>

   <div class="headermenu">test5</div>
 </div>
```

and if I add `<form>` it doesn't work... see html code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" name="form1">    
    <select class="form-field">
    <option>test</option> 
    </select>

    <select class="form-field" >
    <option>test2</option>
    </select>

    <div class="headermenu">test3</div> 

    <select class="form-field" >
    <option>test4</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

look at image for working and non working image....

here is my CSS:

```
.header{width: 100%; background-color: #5e6172;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
align-items: center;    /* vertical align */
justify-content: center;    /* horizontal align */
position: fixed;
top:0; 
height: 80px;
} 

 .headertitle{color: #ffffff; font-size: 1.7em; font-family: h35; margin: 0 0.5%; 
 font-weight:bold; display: inline-block;}

 .headermenu{color: #ffffff; font-size: 1.4em; font-family: h35; margin: 0 0.3%; 
 display: inline-block;}

.form-field {background: #fff; color: #5e6172; padding:4px;  font-family: h35; 
 font-size: 1.2em; margin: 0 0.4%; }

.form-field:focus {background: #e0dedf;    color: #725129;    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add `display: inline-flex` to `form` to fix the container's width:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k7xgneeh/1/)

Comment: Thank you... but I see your TEST3 is slightly above the vertical center compare to the other ones.. how could I correct that ?

Comment: @user3011784 what browser are you on?

Comment: can you post a screen shot? im on chrome and im not seeing an alignment issue

Comment: well, it works well on my site.. the FiDDLE shows a slight problem, but on my site it's fine.. so thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The `.header` is a Flexbox, and it should have direct flex children, but `<form>` is blocking it.

Just add `display: contents` style to `<form>` so it will be ignored in CSS box/layout.

```
form {
    display: contents;
}
```